# 5V to 12V DC-DC converter to power an 11 watt bulb

Tags: dc-dc-converter, watts

I am trying to find a schematic to make a 5V to 12V DC-DC converter to power an 11 watt bulb.

I don't know how to tell if a circuit will be able to light up the bulb.

I found a schematic that might work but I don't know if I can get a high enough wattage.

Could someone check it out to verify if it would work or not, and if not provide a solution?

[image]

https://www.electronics-lab.com/project/5v-to-12v-step-up-dc-dc-converter/

Comment: First step - check the [LM2577 data sheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2577.pdf) With 5V in and 12V out the best you can possibly get from that device is 10.5W

Answer (score 1):

Incandescewnt lamps require large starting currents. Use a more capable boost converter.

Comment: This  ^^^  You need fantastically more current to get the filament to "strike" before it backs off to normal operation.   It has to get hot before it begins to emit light, and during that time, it's resistance is much much lower than when hot.   The regulator above will probably go into current-limit shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed, the starting load will be huge but that is not all, 11 watts at 12v means 916 milliAmps but on 5v it will require you will need atleast 2.2 Amps, add losses to that because boost converters aren't that efficient, you will be spending 2.5+ Amps on input side

Now if you take starting load of the bulb into account, if your 5v supply is not that capable, like for example a smartphone charger, forget about it, no matter what boost converter circuit you have.

You should look for a boost converter that uses external mosfet so you can use a capable mosfet with proper heatsink and a good inductor

Answer (score 0):

As stated by others, it wont work. The solution is to use a premade DC-DC module that is rated for 11W. It's cheaper, requires less of your time and will probably work better. Another solution would be to just use 12V power supply as those are also cheep.

Answer (score 0):

This part looks like it could supply around 19Watts.  Equation 17 on page 16 shows it sourcing 0.871A at 24V.  And the output current is inversely proportional to the output voltage, so it should give 1.742A at 12V.   (https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps55340.pdf?ts=1610812582094&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FTPS55340)